# How I can delete Checked user in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

How I can delete Checked user in Django?

After following answers on Stack-overflow, I've got the code below. However, I try to delete checked users from the database by checked them then press delete using Ajax but when I press the delete nothing happens at all, 
also on the server side it doesn't get `POST`.

**views.py**

```
def delete_list (request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        selected_tests = request.POST['test_list_ids']
        selected_tests = json.loads(selected_tests)
        for i, test in enumerate(selected_tests):
            if test != '':
                User.objects.filter(id__in=selected_tests).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/about')
```

**any.html**

```
<body>
  <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-round delete-btn" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="material-icons" action >delete</i>   Delete
  </button>

  <div class="table-container">
    <table id="fresh-table" class="table table-striped test-list">
      <thead class="thead-table-list">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="checkall" type="checkbox" value="">
                <span class="form-check-sign">
                  <span class="check"></span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th scope="col">Id</th>
          <th scope="col">username</th>
          <th scope="col">email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for test in list_wait %}
        <tr data-id="{{ test.id }}">
          <td>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input class="form-check-input check-ele" type="checkbox" value="">
                <span class="form-check-sign">
                  <span class="check"></span>
                </span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>{{ test.id}}</td>
          <td>{{ test.username}}</td>
          <td>{{ test.email}}</td>
        </tr>      
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  {% csrf_token %}
  </div>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    var selected_rows=[];
    $('.test-list').find('tr').each(function(){
      var row=$(this);
      console.log(row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'));
      if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        console.log(row.attr('data-id'));
        selected_rows.push(row.attr('data-id'));
      };
    });

    var selected_rows = JSON.stringify(selected_rows);
    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'delete_list' %}",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'test_list_ids': selected_rows,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
    })
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

If anyone can help me, I will be very appreciated.

Comment: Difficult to say what's the problem. You added `console.log` statements, what do they show? And maybe add a `.fail() and .done()` completion handlers to your `ajax` call in order to at least do some `console.log` for the results of the call. That'll help check what's going on.

Comment: Have you check what's going on in the request with the developer tools of the browser?